# Obtener elemento de List con lambdas

Tags: java, lista, java-8, lambda

Estoy intentando migrar un código a Java 8, relacionado con los clásicos ejercicios de *Estudiante/Profesor/Asignatura*. Tengo unas dudas sobre si estoy realizando correctamente esta lambda para seleccionar un Estudiante por id (campo Long) de un List.

Código de obtener

```
return Student.getStudents().stream()
    .filter(student -> id.equals(student.getID()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .get(0);
```

La otra duda es, por otro lado intento realizar una inserción en una Lista siempre comprobando que no existe el campo id en la lista de estudiantes, iterativo lo soluciono, pero no encajo aún como verlo con lambdas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas coleccionar los resultados en una lista, esto hará que filtre todos los elementos cuando bien puedes detener la navegación del `Stream` con el primer resultado encontrado. Puedes cambiar tu lambda así:

```
//student debería ir en minúscula
//si Student#getStudents es un método estático, te recomiendo
//cambiar el diseño
Optional<Student> optStudent = student.getStudents().stream()
    .filter(s -> id.equals(s.getID()))
    .findFirst(); //al encontrar el primero, se detiene la iteración del stream y devuelve un Optional
//evaluamos si el optional posee datos
//si no posee datos, entonces devolvemos null (lo clásico)
//la idea de usar Optional es no devolver null y evitar
//el clásico (if var == null)
//considera que Optional#get lanza una excepción en caso que
//no se haya encontrado un resultado
return optStudent.isPresent() ? optStudent.get() : null;
```

Para ingresar un elemento en una lista no necesitas lambdas ni iteraciones, lo que necesitas es buscar si existe el elemento. Para ello, puedes utilizar el código mostrado previamente, así:

```
public Optional<Student> findStudent(Integer id) {
    return studentList.stream()
        .filter(s -> id.equals(s.getID()))
        .findFirst();
}

public boolean insert(Student student) {
    boolean result = false;
    Optional<Student> optStudent = findStudent(student.getId());
    if (!optStudent.isPresent()) {
        studentList.add(student);
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```